# Pointwise convergence in R^R (Topology)

Tags: general-topology

I have a question that I have been strugling with in my topology exercise. I think I am not understanding what  pointwice convergence in box topology is  and I am very confused. So can someone tell if what I am saying right now is correct?

I am given $X=\mathbb{R^{R}}$
  with the box topology. ($\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$
  is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$
  to $\mathbb{R}$
 ) So every open set $U$
  in the box topolog is in the form $U=\underset{i\in\mathbb{R}}{\prod}(a_{i},b_{i})$
 . So pointwise convergence in the metric space is $\forall x_{0}\in\mathbb{R},\,\forall\epsilon>0,\,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\,\,n>N\Rightarrow|f_{n}(x_{0})-f(x_{0})|<\epsilon$
 In any topology, I think the definition of pointwise convergence would be, $\forall x_{0}\in\mathbb{R},\,\forall U$ a neighborhood of $f(x_{0}),\,\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\,\,n>N\Rightarrow f_{n}(x_{0})\in U$
  Is this true? What I am struggling to understand is how $f_{n}(x_{0})\in U$
  if every $U$
  open set is in the form of $U=\underset{i\in\mathbb{R}}{\prod}(a_{i},b_{i})$
  . So there is something here that I am not defining well. Can someone point out what the problem is? Thank you

Comment: Your reasoning seems ok to me-it's not clear what you don't understand and exactly what your question is.

Comment: There is an inconsistency.Elements of  U and $f_{n}(x_{0})$  are not in the same space. because $f_{n}(x_{0})$  is just  a sequence and the U is ''uncountable'' product of open sets (I don't know if that's the correct term). Or there is something that I am misunderstanding. Is my question clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you have a fairly important misunderstanding of the box topology. It is not true that every open set $U$ in the box topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is of the form $U=\prod_{i\in\Bbb R}(a_i,b_i)$: the sets of that form are a *base* for the box topology, which therefore consists of all unions of sets of that form.

What is really getting in your way, though, is a misunderstanding of what it means for a sequence of points in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ to converge pointwise. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $x^{(n)}=\langle x_i^{(n)}:i\in\Bbb R\rangle$ be a point of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, and let $x=\langle x_i:i\in\Bbb R\rangle\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. Then $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence of points of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. When we say that this sequence *converges pointwise* to $x$, we mean that for each $i\in\Bbb R$, the sequence $\langle x_i^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of real numbers converges to $x_i$ in $\Bbb R$. In other words, for each $i\in\Bbb R$ and open nbhd $U$ of $x_i$ in $\Bbb R$ there is an $m_{i,U}\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_i^{(n)}\in U$ whenever $n\ge m_{i,U}$.

In other words, the sequence $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ converges pointwise to $x$ if and only if each of the coordinate sequences $\langle x_i^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x_i$ in $\Bbb R$ as an ordinary sequence of real numbers.